# How to get rid of square bracket and single quotes when printing in python

Tags: python-2.7

I can't get to print my dictionary keys without brackets and single quotes. I am a bit stranded here.

I am trying to get data from ldap with the ldap module, getting a list of users and then getting attributes and their values basically. Then I want to print those values in a csv file.

So far the result looks like:

['valueuid'];['valueSN'];['valueGivenname'];['valueo'];;;;

so - I am almost there :-)

this is the code so far ... I have removed some vars.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import collections
import ldap
import ldap.filter

# vars
countries = ["10", "11", "12", "13", "14"]

# open connection to ldap
l = ldap.initialize(ldap_server)
try:
  l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
  #l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
  print(e)

for country in countries:
  # create ldap user list
  searchBase = "ou=employees,l=" + country + ",o=enterprise,dc=acme,dc=com"
  searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
  searchName = "(uid=*)"
  fieldList = ["uid"]
  user = l.search_s(searchBase, searchScope, searchName, fieldList)
  users = [entry for dn, entry in user if isinstance(entry, dict)]

  # Create/Open file for write
  outputfile = open("ava-user_" + country + ".csv","w+")

  print("Getting userattributes from Country: ", country)
  print("Writing to file: ava-user_" + country + ".csv")
  print("")
  # print header to file
  print("uid;givenname;sn;o;attrtibute1;attrtibute2;attrtibute3;attrtibute4", file = outputfile)

  for user in users:
    # create attribut list for user
    user = ','.join(user['uid'])
    searchBase = "uid=" + user + ",ou=employees,l=" + country + ",o=enterprise,dc=acme,dc=com"
    searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    searchName = "(uid=" + user + ")"
    fieldList = ["uid", "givenname", "sn", "o", "attrtibute1", "attrtibute2", "attrtibute3",  "attrtibute4"]
    userattr = l.search_s(searchBase, searchScope, searchName, fieldList)

    # remove uid from list
    userattr = [entry for uid, entry in userattr if isinstance(entry, dict)]

    # convert userattr from list into a dictionary
    res = {}
    for dicto in userattr:
      res.update(dicto)
      userattr = {}
      userattr = res

    # add missing key if it was empty from ldap
    for key in fieldList:
      if key not in userattr.keys():
        userattr[key] = ""

    # print userattributes to file
    print('%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s' % (userattr['uid'], userattr['givenname'], userattr['sn'], userattr['o'], userattr['attrtibute1'], userattr['attrtibute2'], userattr['attrtibute3'], userattr['attrtibute4']), file = outputfile)

  # closing file handle
  outputfile.close()

print("Done")

sys.exit()
```

But the output is supposed to look like ...

valueuid;valueSN;valueGivenname;valueo;;;;

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well - just found a possible solution. Cutting off the first and last 2 characters after changing it to a string.

in the print command:

str(userattr['attrtibute1'])[2:-2]

maybe there is a more elegant way ?

```
    # add missing key if it was empty from ldap
for key in fieldList:
  if key not in userattr.keys():
    userattr[key] = "['']"

# print userattributes to file
print('%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s' % (str(userattr['uid'])[2:-2], str(userattr['givenname'])[2:-2], str(userattr['sn'])[2:-2], str(userattr['o'])[2:-2], str(userattr['attrtibute1'])[2:-2], str(userattr['attrtibute2'])[2:-2], str(userattr['attrtibute3'])[2:-2], str(userattr['attrtibute4'])[2:-2]), file = outputfile)
```